# Fit data to a linear combination of non-linear function

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Consider this:

```
clear all
clc
close all

x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 2.*sin(x) + 0.1.*rand(1,length(x));
mdl = fitlm(x,y);
plotAdded(mdl)
```

The unknown parameters are the coefficients of 2sin(x), that is +1. So, the model is linear, however, "fitlm" does not work here as it tries to fit the data to a model like "a*x+b". I want it to fit the data to a model like asin(x) + b; the a and b are the unknown. How, can I fit the data to a linear combination of non-linear functions or custom functions. I need a solution that works for other functions such as Cos, Log, Exp or user defined functions.

I would like to do this fitting with statistics toolbox and programmatically.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but from what i get you may want to look at the documentation of lsqr or lsqlin.

Answer (score 0):

The linear model only permits linear functions. But you can do your customized functions like this:

```
mdl = fitlm(sin(x),y);
```

It looks good:

[image: The result]